# Q.all and an array of promises don't seem to be working

Tags: node.js, q, node-mysql

I'm trying to use Q to do some work. I loop through and call a function which saves data to the database and returns a promise. Once those are done I need to do something else, but the Q.all finishes, although I can see each resolve being called. I've going nuts, any ideas?

The setup:

```
// save the divisions and then do the division checks
// data.divisions is an array of objects
var promises = [];
data.divisions.forEach(function(dd){
    var d = new grpl.division.Division(dd),
        p = d.save();
    promises.push(p);
});

Q.all(promises)
.then(function(){
    // do some other stuff here
    // this never actually gets called

}).fail(function(err){
    cb(err);
}).done();
```

And here's `d.save()`

```
Division.prototype.save = function(){
    var self = this
        d = Q.defer();

    getPool().getConnection(function(err, db){
        if(err){ d.reject(err); return false; }

        var fields = {
            division_id: self.division_id,
            season_id: self.season_id,
            title: self.title,
            cap: self.cap,
            display_order: self.display_order
        };

        db.query("INSERT INTO division SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?", [fields, fields], function(err, result) {
            if(err){ d.reject(err); return false; }
            d.resolve(true);// this does get resolved for each division
        });
    });

    return d.promise;
}
```

I have no clue what's wrong, but it just stops and doesnt appear to ever resolved my Q.all call.

**UPDATE**
It appears that the initial call to save will function properly, but subsequent save calls appear to be resolving the same promise as the first call. I wrapped the body of the save code into a variable function which I called from save and its working but I'm not 100% sure why (prototypical inheritance is my fallback whenever JS really confuses me). Any explanations or better ways to do it?

```
Division.prototype.save = function(){
    var func = function(self){
        var d = Q.defer();

        d.promise.division_id = self.division_id;

        getPool().getConnection(function(err, db){
            if(err){ d.reject(err); return false; }

            var fields = {
                division_id: self.division_id,
                season_id: self.season_id,
                title: self.title,
                cap: self.cap,
                display_order: self.display_order
            };

            db.query("INSERT INTO division SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?", [fields, fields], function(err, result) {
                if(err){ d.reject(err); return false; }
                d.resolve(result);
            });
        });

        return d.promise;
    }

    return func(this);
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you call `.save` directly without the `.all`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth not sure what you mean without the `all` since `save` is being called independent of the `all`, it's just the returned promises from `save` that gets added to the array that `all` works on. But now that I say that I could see how it may be storing the reference to the save function instead of the returned promise. Will have to try that when I get home.

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't it. I've edited the code to show my update

Comment: Sorry, my question is, given your code, what makes you say that `.all` is the problem, vs any number of other things? If you do `d.save().then(function(){ ... });`, does that run?

Comment: If `save` does work, then can you distill the problem down to not include any of your DB logic? Your example right now is pretty big.

Comment: after lots of changes and poking around, the resolve call in d was acting properly for the first call, but subsequent calls were acting on the same defered object as the first call, while the array passed to all had the individual promises. I wrapped the body of my save function in a variable function and returned the call to that and now everything is working fine. I'm assuming it had something to do with prototypical inheritance, but really have no clue.

Comment: I suspect most of your issues stem from the fact that you're mixing callbacks with promises (such as when you call `getPool().getConnection()` and `db.query()`). You have to convert Node-style callbacks into promises first. So, instead of manually creating a promise using `Q.defer()`, instead have a look at [`Q.denodeify()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdenodeifynodefunc-args), or one of the similar helper methods (`Q.nbind`, `Q.nfapply`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, your debugging comments solved the problem and made it clear what I was missing. It is an incredibly small typo, and is one of the reasons I'd recommend using something like JSHint on your code.

```
Division.prototype.save = function(){
    var self = this
        d = Q.defer();
```

Can you see it? I didn't until your comments made it very clear what was going wrong.

```
Division.prototype.save = function(){
    var self = this
                   ^
        d = Q.defer();
```

You are missing a `,`, so `d` is a global variable, instead of scoped within `save`, so every time you call `.save()`, you rewrite the global, and all of your attempts to `resolve` and `reject` will resolve the same global, instead of the defered for each save call.

Comment: Ah yes, JavaScript's [automatic semicolon insertion](http://wtfjs.com/2013/03/27/automatic-semicolon-insertion). Thanks, JavaScript, you're so helpful!

Comment: Yep, that was it. Of course something small and stupid. Thanks for your help man.